# Why does the same script (GUI) look so different on other Computer ? (customtkinter)

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

So i wrote a program on one Laptop, but now I bought a new one and wanted to run the same code on my new Laptop and it looks sooo different. I am using a Framework called customtkinter to make the GUI. The Python and the Ubuntu Version on both Laptops are the same, everything updated and upgraded. My new Laptop has a resolution of 3000x2000 and my old was 1920x1080 but that cant be the case even if I increase the dimensions in my Script this wont work. The versions of the libaries i am using are the same as they where on my old laptop. Please help!

```html
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import *
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Window config
        root = CTk()
        root.title("Kassa System")
        root.geometry(f"{1920}x{1080}")
        root.resizable(False,False)
        
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AldB.jpg)
[The old one, this is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPLHs.jpg)

This is how it looks like on the new Laptop:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1KDP.jpg)

i tried reinstalling the libaries and changing the python interpreteur.

I provided a bit of the code.

Comment: Are there different "themes" for Ubuntu? Maybe the OS is the same but set with a different "theme"?

Comment: You may need to ask the author of customtkinter. Maybe they designed it to look different.

Comment: Check whether there is a *Scale* setting in system *Display* configuration. If yes, check whether the setting is set to same value in the two Laptops.

Comment: See [ask]. You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. Post a screenshot instead of a photograph. And describe what are expected and what are displayed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is that really a [mre]? Then, post screenshots for that code. And describe what are expected and what are displayed. And did you check the scale setting as acw1668 said?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @acw1668 i managed to solve the problem. It was a scaling problem. Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Hey Venom453, welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for following up on responding with your own answer to your own question! To improve that answer, could you please update it to include what exact steps you took so other people having the same problem can follow them?